# WPF Custom Control with Databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I'm looking to create a custom control which represents a hand.

This at needs to be bound to a datasource, then if a value/index value is present in the datasource which is representing a particular finger, the finger in question should appear green.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to start of with such control?

Basically I'm creating an app which records which fingers people where their rings and how many.

So graphics on each finger will show Green plus a number showing how many.

[Rough Hand Design for User Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S5DG.png)

Any help or direction will be mostly appreciative.

Comment: Start reading here: [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Comment: Wouldn't it look better if there was a coloured band per ring? How many rings do people wear as a max? You also wouldn't need to split out the finger and thumbs into separate geometries then.

Comment: Re the coloured bands.  Great Idea.  Was hoping to get going with the basics, then make better once I know more about how to start off.

Splitting out the finger & Thumbs is just a visual thing.  Making it look like a hand, as there would be 2.  Each finer being indexed from 0 through 9 in order from pinky to pinky.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend a usercontrol rather than custom control for this. As I think that link Clemens posted says, unless you really are going to switch out the template of the control then you don't need to do a custom control - which would be harder than a usercontrol.

This will have at least one dependency property you're going to bind your collection to. Make that an ObservableCollection.  You can then pass say 0,1,0,2,0. If people change the rings they wear super dynamically you can set one of the collection to itself to cover change notification to the control.

Inside this I'd put a viewbox with a canvas in it.
Grab an outline of a hand from somewhere. You want to get a geometry out of this so look for a svg preferably.
Maybe https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/stop-hand-silhouette_57659

Then download and install InkScape.
Use this to trace bitmap if that's all you have then save as > xaml.
Open that file in notepad and you'll see a path with a set of sort of co-ordinates. Grab those. These can be used to define a geometry you use as a resource or directly used as the Data to a path.
I use such a resource for the email "icon" in this:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32610.wpf-layout-lab.aspx

Or you could probably use one of the hand icons from syncfusion's metro studio ( free ) https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio

A Path can be used for your hand.
You then want 5 itemscontrols for your thumbs and fingers.
You could maybe make each of them a usercontrol as well but I'd try 5 controls for a first iteration.
They should template each item they're given into a green rectangle defined in itemtemplate.

Position 5 of them to taste on your hand's digits.

Bind their itemssources by index to your collection and use a converter to return the number of objects specified by that. So if it's 3 then you generate three objects.

That viewbox is there to scale everything.  So you can size your control however you like and the rings will stay on the fingers.

Comment: Thanks.  I was just wondering about doing it via a usercontrol as it happens :).  


So regarding the binding.  I was originally thinking of passing in a collection of (Int, int).  Items will only exisit if they have at least 1 ring on that finger.  I was hoping to use the collection for both purposes.  
So if itemscollections contain at least 1 entry for an index it would go green, then show the count of entries for each index as a value for each finger.


Should I add all this logic in the code behind of a UserControl?

Comment: If it's observablecollection<int> you always have 5 numbers. 0 means no rings, no objects added to that finger's itemssource and no green bands. 1 means 1 object and one band. I don't think you need any code behind in the usercontrol, just the converter.